# Update a value in array of objects MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    {
      "name": "user2",
      "avatar": 1,
      "email": "example@gmail.com",
      "categories": [
        {
          "cname": "Category 1",
          "list": [
            {
              "status": "pending",
              "name": "List Item 1"
            },
            {
              "status": "pending",
              "name": "List Item 2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to update "categories.list.status" = "pending" to "completed". How can I do it? I tried using positional operator($) but it is giving error too many positional operator.

Comment: For all list elements?

Comment: No, only for a single list item where name is "List Item 2"

Comment: Have you checked out [arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#examples)?

Comment: I am new to MongoDb. I don't know how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mongoose (as your tags suggest), you can just update the value in the document object and then save it

```js
document.list[0].status = "completed";
document.save();
```

Comment: I think it will change only the first document. I want to change status based on cname and name.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. It worked.

```
    document.updateOne({_id: id}, {
    {
        $set: {
              "categories.$[].list.$[ele].status" : status
             }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [{"ele.name" : name}]
    }
    }
```